# how can i check all ul of nested checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

## Question:

I have a category listing which some categories have children, I am trying to create a ALL category that when clicked, will check all sibling checkboxes in that same category.

e.g; clicking **ALL** underneath the **MUSIC** category would check `blues, jazz, rock n roll`

## Code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul name="events-categories" id="events-categories">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="category-events" value="185" placeholder="" id="category-185" class="events-category"> CONVENTIONS
        <ul class="event-children">
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-all" value="" class="events-child-category-all">ALL</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-190" value="190" id="child-category-190" class="child events-child-category">SCIENCE</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-191" value="191" id="child-category-191" class="child events-child-category">TECHNOLOGY</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="category-events" value="184" placeholder="" id="category-184" class="events-category"> MUSIC
        <ul class="event-children">
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-all" value="" class="events-child-category-all">ALL</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-189" value="189" id="child-category-189" class="child events-child-category">BLUES</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-188" value="188" id="child-category-188" class="child events-child-category">JAZZ</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="child-category-187" value="187" id="child-category-187" class="child events-child-category">ROCK N ROLL</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="category-events" value="186" placeholder="" id="category-186" class="events-category"> TRIBUTES</li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.event-children {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}​
```

**jQuery So Far:**

```
/**
 * left sidebar events categories
 * toggle sub categories
 */
$('.events-category').change( function(){
    console.log('showing sub categories');
    var c = this.checked;
    if( c ){
        $(this).next('.event-children').css('display', 'block');
    }else{
        $(this).next('.event-children').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

$('.events-child-category-all').change( function(){
    var c = this.checked;
    if( c ){
        $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
    }else{
        $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    }
});​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SENV8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.events-child-category-all').change( function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SENV8/3/

Comment: Now, if i wanted an "ALL" checkbox at the very top `ul` level, how would i do that as well? It would check all parents, and children throughout the entire list.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yep, but depends on jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this, because those `checkboxes` aren't `siblings`

```
$('.events-child-category-all').change( function(){
    var c = this.checked;
    if( c ){
        $(this).closest('.event-children').find(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
    }else{
        $(this).closest('.event-children').find(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    }
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/SENV8/1/)

Comment: out of the answer you, nnnnnn, ahren provided which would be the best of them as far as performance

Comment: @Mike, you can use xdazz's one, it will save you a `if-else` check.

Comment: `input[type=checkbox]` is a more efficient selector than `:checkbox` (according to the [doco](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)), but really a user isn't going to notice the difference between any of the answers on something like this with only a small number of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$(".events-child-category-all").click(function() {
   $(this).closest("ul").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",this.checked);
});
```

The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up the DOM tree looking for a matching element, in this case finding the "ul" that the checkbox is located in.

If you're using a version of jQuery older than 1.6 you'll need `.attr()` instead of [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Why not `.prop("checked", this.checked)` ? He need uncheck when uncheck all.

Comment: Thanks @xdazz, yes, I didn't realise that at first. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ahren/SENV8/2/

```
$('.events-child-category-all').change( function(){
    var c = this.checked;
    if( c ){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $(this).parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    }
});​
```

There are no `siblings` to the input that `change` fired from. You first need to go up one level to the parent `li`, then grab it's `siblings`, and use `find()` to get their checkboxes. Or you could use `children()` instead of `find()`